# Blob image returns blank image

Tags: javascript, html, image, blob, todataurl

I'm trying to extract image information from canvas data and display it in a .png file. Thus far I've been able to extract the Base64 information from the canvas using the toDataURL() method and create a blob object (which is correctly identified as a .png image) but the image is always blank. Any suggestions? Here's the code

```
        var canvasData = markup.find('canvas');
        var imageDataURL = canvasData[4].toDataURL("image/png");
        var theData = atob(imageDataURL.substring('data:image/png;base64,'.length)), asArray = new Uint8Array(theData.length);
        for (var i = 0, len = theData.length; i < len; ++i) {
            asArray[i] = theData.charCodeAt(i);
        }
        var blob = new Blob([asArray.buffer], { type: 'image/png' }); saveAs(blob, 'export_' + Date.now() + '.png');
```

Interestingly the size is correct, the only thing missing is the actual image within the .png.

Comment: Why do you need blob object?

Comment: To get the image to display. The order of processing goes canvas -> Base64 -> Blob

Where canvas is how the data is displayed originally, Base64 data is returned when toDataURL is called and the Blob object takes in that Base64 data. From here I want to generate the image from the Blob

Comment: I take it `saveAs` saves the `Blob` as a file? Why not just start a download from the URL `imageDataURL`?

Comment: _To get the image to display._ You don't need Blob for that. Just create new image element from canvas content and place it into DOM.

Comment: So myImage = new Image(); and myImage = canvasData[4].toDataURL("image/png");?

Comment: @Novastorm Almost, but not quite: `myImage = new Image(); myImage.src = canvasData[4].toDataURL("image/png"); document.body.appendChild(myImage);`

Comment: Thank you! I'll give that a go

Comment: Just tried that - it looks like the output is still the Base64 string as opposed to an image

Comment: _it looks like the output is still the Base64 string_ Most likely something wrong with your canvas. BTW: Why do you get 5th element (`canvasData[4]`)?

Comment: I'll take a look into the canvas. Ah that was just for testing, I had originally iterated over all the data in canvasData (which was > 50) so I just chose a random number from it rather than looking at all 50+ items

Comment: Thank you everyone for your help and advice on this; it turns out the method .find wasn't returning the correct data. By changing that to document.getElementsByTagName("canvas") it returned all the correct canvas information and toDataURL() then worked correctly

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `saveAs` function initiates a file download, you can take a shortcut by just assigning the data URL to an `a` element, set `a.download` to the desired file name, and using `a.click()` to start the file download:

```js
function canvasToFile()
{
    var canvas = document.getElementsByTagName('canvas')[0];
    canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(img, 0, 0);
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    a.href = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    a.download = 'export_' + Date.now() + '.png';
    a.style.display = 'none';
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.click();
}
// For demo:
var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0];
img.crossOrigin = 'Anonymous';
img.addEventListener('load', canvasToFile);
img.src = 'http://lorempixel.com/400/400/';
```

```html
<canvas width="400" height="400"/>
<img/>
```

In some browsers it is not necessary to append `a` to the DOM tree (hence the lines `a.style.display = 'none';` and `document.body.appendChild(a);` could be omitted), but in others (Firefox for example, if I'm not mistaken) it is.